# strapi-docker lodash issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, strapi

I'm having issues with the official docker wrapper for strapi.io --> whenever I run `docker-compose up`, I am getting errors for lodash to not have been found. When running the docker container for the very first time (clean install), everything is running smoothly, second attempt will return the error below.

```
api_1  | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:550
api_1  |     throw err;
api_1  |     ^
api_1  | 
api_1  | Error: Cannot find module 'lodash'
api_1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:15)
api_1  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:475:25)
api_1  |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
api_1  |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:11:18)
api_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/api/strapi-app/admin/controllers/Admin.js:5:11)
api_1  |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
api_1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
api_1  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
api_1  |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
api_1  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
```

Do you guys have any idea? Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: same here? can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is related to the node version.

> Strapi needs Node v10 to be installed in order to work. If you upgrade
>   your node version it should be working properly

I still had issues with v10 so I downgraded to:

**node: 9.11.2**

**npm: 5.6.0**